# How to open iframe on the same page

Tags: php, html, iframe

What I need, I have xxx.php webpage which connect to PostgreSQL DB, send some query and result is displayed inside the iframe. Then I have simple yyy.html page where I have form for searching inside DB, but I want to open iframe on the same page (after sql query is done), not by opening another page. Is that possible to do it? It works in my case just by creating another page.
I hope it is clear.

Thank you

```
<?php
$kpc = $_POST["kpc"];
$ku= $_POST ["ku"];
```

```html
    <body>
    <script>
       function klik(){
           document.getElementById("maps").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="xxx.php" ></object>';
       } 
     </script>
    <form action="datab.php" method="post">
    text: <input type="text" name="kpc"><br>
    text2: <input type="text" name="ppc"><br>
    <input type="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    
    <iframe id="maps">
        
    </iframe> 
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The content of an iframe element is *alternative content to display if iframes are not supported*.

If you want to display content on the same page, then **don't use an iframe**.

`<object type="text/html"` is more-or-less the same as an iframe anyway. You could just not use that:

```
document.getElementById("maps").src = "xxx.php";
```

… for that matter you could remove the JavaScript and just submit the form directly to the frame:

```
<form action="xxx.php" target="name_of_iframe">
```